# How to install Python's `ipcqueue` dependency on Windows?

Tags: python, linux, windows, posix, mqueue

When trying to install Python's `ipcqueue` on Windows 10, I'm getting the following error:

`.../ipcqueue/posixmq.h(5): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mqueue.h': No such file or directory`

That's expected, since `ipcqueue` requires Python header files ([link](https://pypi.org/project/ipcqueue/)), and I don't know how to get those files on Windows or if it's even possible to do so. I've spent some time researching online, but since I'm no expert when it comes to these things, I've come here to ask for your help. The closest thing I've found is the [mqueue-w32](https://github.com/marklakata/mqueue-w32) GitHub repo, but it's for Windows 32 only.

Hopefully there's a simple way to solve my problem. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can run Windows 32 programs on Windows 64, if that's what you are worried about, it will just maybe have less stuff.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).